# Getting browser scroll position in ios

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, browser

I am having an annoying problem which only seems to occur on ios. I am trying to get the scroll position so that I can update a button to lead you up or down on the page depending on where you are, like this:

```
const scrollPos = (window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0);
```

This works fine on my windows computer, mac, an android phone, in multiple browsers, but not on my ipad or iphone. There it is just always 0, except for when you scroll past the top or bottom of a page, which is strange.

I've seen some posts about the scroll position not updating until you finish scrolling, but this is not the same problem that I have. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This solved itself. I went to work on other parts, and suddenly it was working. I have no idea what solved it.